# Adding a counter to a prev/next image slideshow(javascript/css only)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, counter

I have created a "prev/next" slideshow using javascript, now I want to add a counter(1/10, 2/10, 3/10...) beside my "prev/next" buttons but nothing seemed to work.

This is my first time attempting to make a website, I know nothing about jQuery, so please stick with html+javascript if possible. Here is my script

```
var image = new Array(
"http://i990.photobucket.com/albums/af24/callmeaaaaj/AJ/_MG_7747.jpg", 
"http://i990.photobucket.com/albums/af24/callmeaaaaj/AJ/1109163s.jpg")

var imgNumber=1

var numberOfImg=2

function previousImage(){
  if(imgNumber>1){
     imgNumber--
  }

  else{
    imgNumber = numberOfImg
    }

  document.slideImage.src = image[imgNumber-1]
}

function nextImage(){
  if(imgNumber < numberOfImg){
  imgNumber++
  }

  else{
    imgNumber = 1
    }

  document.slideImage.src = image[imgNumber-1]
    }

if(document.images){
   var image1 = new Image()
   image1.src = "http://i990.photobucket.com/albums/af24/callmeaaaaj/AJ/_MG_7747.jpg"
   var image2 = new Image()
   image2.src = "http://i990.photobucket.com/albums/af24/callmeaaaaj/AJ/1109163s.jpg"
   }
```

Script+html: http://jsfiddle.net/nLHY9/5/

(Prev/Next buttons seem not to be working on this----they work fine when I launched them from laptop to browser.)

Comment: If an answer below is helpful, would you please click the accept checkmark next to the best answer?

Answer (score 0):

you could have used some existing javascript image sliders, for example, [sliderman slider](http://www.devtrix.net/sliderman/index.html), for your current code, you can do like, add an element like `span`, to hold the count, and you could add a function like:

```
function changeCounter(cur, total) {
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = cur + "/" + total;
}
```

and call it in your `previousImage()` and `nextImage()` functions, as in this demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLHY9/6/)

Answer (score 0):

There are many pure css slideshows that are beautiful and can do impressive things. However, as you try to support older browsers, the pure css slideshows get less and less impressive or even impossible. JavaScript is the most flexible and powerful way to go. That being, I wanted to help you clean up your code. I only had a few minutes, so this is a quickly thrown together plugin, but it should get you on the right track.

#### First, a few notes on your code:

```
//you're missing semicolons everywhere. ";"
/* "var image" is very unclear.
 * it's an array, so it should be plural "images"
 * there aren't images in this array - it's image urls or sources
 * instead of "new Array" you could just use "[]"
 */
var image = new Array(
"http://i990.photobucket.com/albums/af24/callmeaaaaj/AJ/_MG_7747.jpg", 
"http://i990.photobucket.com/albums/af24/callmeaaaaj/AJ/1109163s.jpg")

var imgNumber=1 //the name doesn't mean anything. I have to assume that you mean "currentImgNumber" or something to that effect

var numberOfImg=2 //this could be determined by checking the length of your array -  myArray.length
```

#### And here's my exampe plugin:

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/IkAcEdO/3/edit)

```
/***** This section is how you use the plugin. I start writing with the usage and then I make it mean something *****/

window.onload = function() { //when the page is loaded
  var fooElem = document.getElementById('foo'); //get an element where we will attach the plugin
  var foo = Object.create(slideshow); //create a new slideshow object
  foo.create({ //create a slideshow with the given options
    element: fooElem, //the element where the slideshow will be
    sources: [ //image urls
      "http://i990.photobucket.com/albums/af24/callmeaaaaj/AJ/_MG_7747.jpg",
      "http://i990.photobucket.com/albums/af24/callmeaaaaj/AJ/1109163s.jpg"  
    ]
  });

  //we can make more of these and with different options
  var barElem = document.getElementById('bar');
  var bar = Object.create(slideshow);
  bar.create({
    element: barElem,
    sources: [
      "http://eggboss.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/The-Gentleman-233x300.png",
      "http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/040/8/a/profile_picture_by_classy_like_a_sir-d5uf426.jpg"  
    ]
  });
};


/**** now let's create the plugin and make it work as it is used above *****/
var slideshow = {
  currentIndex: 0,
  imgs: [],
  create: function(options) {
    options.element.className+= ' slideshow'; //add a class to the main element for styling

    this.imgs = this.getImgs(options.sources); //make img html

    var controls = this.getControls(); //make controls

    //add the html to the element from the options
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    this.imgs.forEach(function(img) {
      frag.appendChild(img);
    });
    frag.appendChild(controls);
    options.element.appendChild(frag);
  },
  getImgs: function(sources) {
    var imgs = [];
    sources.forEach(function(src, i) {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = src;
      imgs.push(img);

      if (i > 0) {
        img.style.display = 'none'; //hide all but first image
      }
    });
    return imgs;
  },
  getControls: function() {
    var that = this; //so that we can access "this" within the click functions

    var controls = document.createElement('div');
    controls.className = 'controls';

    var counter = document.createElement('span');
    counter.className = 'counter';
    this.setCounter(counter);

    var prev = document.createElement('a');
    prev.textContent = 'Prev';
    prev.className = 'prev';
    prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
      newIndex = (that.currentIndex) ? that.currentIndex-1 : that.imgs.length-1;
      that.changeImg(newIndex, counter);
    });

    var next = document.createElement('a');
    next.textContent = 'Next';
    next.className = 'next';
    next.addEventListener('click', function() {
      newIndex = (that.currentIndex !== that.imgs.length-1) ? that.currentIndex+1 : 0;
      that.changeImg(newIndex, counter);
    });

    controls.appendChild(prev);
    controls.appendChild(next);
    controls.appendChild(counter);

    return controls;
  },
  changeImg: function(newIndex, counter) {
    this.imgs[this.currentIndex].style.display = 'none';
    this.imgs[newIndex].style.display = 'inline';
    this.currentIndex = newIndex;
    this.setCounter(counter);
  },
  setCounter: function(counter) {
    counter.textContent = (this.currentIndex+1)+' / '+this.imgs.length;
  }
};
```